# Error as I try to solve a non-linear equation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve an equation given by:

[image]

I converted the above equation into python code given as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

u = lambda b : ((1 - b)(7.864 - 5.336*b + 25.864*np.power(b,2) - 11.935*np.power(b,3) - 0.336*np.power(b,4))) - 6.164

fsolve(u,np.linspace(0,1,10))
```

But I get an error saying:

[image]

What could be the reason for this? What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a * between the (1 - b) and (7.864 ...:

```
In [11]: from scipy.optimize import fsolve
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...: u = lambda b : ((1 - b) * (7.864 - 5.336*b + 25.864*np.power(b,2) - 11.935*np.power(b,3) - 0.336*np.power(b,4))) - 6.164
    ...:                       # ^ MISSING HERE
    ...: fsolve(u,np.linspace(0,1,10))
    ...:
Out[11]:
array([0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009,
       0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009, 0.20503009])
```

Hence the error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`, this is the same as trying to do:

```
In [12]: a
Out[12]: array(42)

In [13]: a()
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

In [14]: a(1)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```